# Safari CSS looks bad on Iphone vs Android Chrome

Tags: css, vue.js

I used Vue.js 3 to show a div of rows, the rows looks fine on android mobiles but on Iphones look bad and I don't know why.
I know the gap property in css not good for iphones web browsers but this is not the case.

[Iphone pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuaUW.jpg)

[Android pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3KkF.jpg)

```css
.product-list {
  display:-webkit-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* gap: 15px; */
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.product-line {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.3rem;
  height: 1.3rem;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-list">
      <template v-for="product in sortedProducts" :key="product.barkod">
        <div class="product-line" :id="product.barkod">
          <div class="product-id" style="width:20%;">{{ product.barkod }}</div>
          <div
            class="product-name"
            style="font-size: 1rem; width:60%; overflow:hidden;"
          >
            <p>{{ product.ItemName }}</p>
          </div>
          <!-- <div class="stock-amount" style="width:25%;">
            <p>{{ product.stock }}</p>
          </div> -->
          <div
            class="product-stock"
            style="font-size: 1.2rem; width:20%; height:90%;"
          >
            <InputText
              type="text"
              v-model="product.currentOrder"
              style="width:100%;"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </template>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you reset your CSS at first, with something like `normalize.css`? Also, did you setup the viewport (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag)? Finally, you can probably remove all the prefixed properties since the properties you're using are well supported (https://caniuse.com/?search=flexbox).

Comment: I didn't reset the CSS. This is the viewport: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: Try doing the other 2.